# How can I hide soft keyboard?

Tags: android

I want to hide soft keyboard from my android application while start the application.
and for that I am using this code but don't get result. please help me. Thanks

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(notes.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in your application's manifest file activity tag..

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the system keyboard and hide it.

```
InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchBar.getApplicationWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```